# Jquery add to links to open in new tab

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am helping a client with their WooCommerce WordPress site and they wand to have it when you click on the product image/link on the category page it opens in a new tab. I've been trying to use jquery to add this but have not been successful. I'm fairly new to jquery and would love any help.

HTML:

```
<ul class="products">
    <li class="post-6568 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail first sale shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-designer-watch-special product-tag-tw-steel instock">   <a href="http://harmonyjewellers.ca/product/tw-steel-7823/">

        <img src="http://harmonyjewellers.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/7823595-400x400.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="7823$595" height="400" width="400">
        <h3>TW Steel (#7823)</h3>



    <span class="price"><del><span class="amount">$1,190.00</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">$714.00</span></ins></span>

    </a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var productLinks = $('ul.products img').find('a');
    prodcutLinks.click(function () {
        $(this).attr("target", "_blank");

    });

});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6nbc6zj8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need jquery for this...just add it in your link itself: `<a href="#" target="_blank"><img></a>`

https://jsfiddle.net/6nbc6zj8/1/

```
<ul class="products">
    <li class="post-6568 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail first sale shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-designer-watch-special product-tag-tw-steel instock">   
        <a href="http://harmonyjewellers.ca/product/tw-steel-7823/" target="_blank">            
            <img src="http://harmonyjewellers.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/7823595-400x400.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="7823$595" height="400" width="400"/>
            <h3>TW Steel (#7823)</h3>            
            <span class="price">
                <del><span class="amount">$1,190.00</span></del> 
                <ins><span class="amount">$714.00</span></ins>
            </span>                       
        </a>        
    </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: if you cant change the html, then you want to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/6nbc6zj8/7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.products li a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

youre targeting the `products li a` elements and jsut adding the attribute on them. your current code only adds it on click, but you want to add the attributes before the click.

Comment: I don't know where to find this link in the WP files. That's why I was turning to jQuery. I am quite familiar with HTML/CSS and how to add the target="_blank". There is also well over a 1000 products to add this to. So even if I knew where the links were that would still take a lot of time.

Comment: If all you need to do is add the target attribute, use this: `$('ul.products  a').attr('target', '_blank');`

Comment: @BrentNicolet can you be specific with what didnt work? are there errors in the console?

Comment: no errors in console. And what didn't work is when the image/link was clicked on, it did not open in a new tab.

Comment: Did you maybe use this exact same line `<a href="#" target="_blank">`, because you need to replace the`#` with your link...

Comment: @Mikey OP isnt altering the html because OP cant find the html to alter...thats why they want a jQuery solution. and @ BrentNicolet, i dont believe i can help you any further without seeing a demo that shows the issue you're having.

Comment: heres a link to the page. if you do view source you can see the jquery is there

http://harmonyjewellers.ca/product-category/designer-watch-special/

Comment: instead of just wrapping it in `<script>` tags, try `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Didn't change anything. I do appreciate your help :)

Comment: in the console, if you copy and paste `$('.products li a').attr('target', '_blank');` this in, and press enter, it applies the correct attributes to all the links. so the line of code is working, the jquery is just not being called or applied correctly.  make sure that nothing else in the `<script>` tags other than that line of code. if you have other jquery/javascript, wrap it in another script tag (for now so we can try to isolate the issue)

Comment: would it be conflicting with any php? I know WP is built heavily with PHP.

Comment: no, you have other javascript errors within the code. that code prevent this javascript from running smoothly.  you have an `undefined is not a function` concerning `flexslider`, and  `prettyphoto`. the wrapping in your script is also wrapping html starting with `<!--[if lt IE 8]>` which it shouldnt be. id say that these are your problems.  the jquery code works, but your site has other issues preventing it from working as it should.

Comment: Nope that wasn't the problem. I feel dumb at this point. I didn't have a closing </script> tag. Thanks for your help @indubitablee

Comment: @BrentNicolet....see my comment of 8 minutes ago... "make sure that nothing else in the `<script>` tags other than that line of code" and the one from 4 minutes ago "the wrapping in your script is also wrapping html starting with `<!--[if lt IE 8]>` which it shouldnt be." glad you found the error.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a good answer and your question might be unclear, but if you *really* want to do it with jQuery I suggest something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/6nbc6zj8/8

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('ul.products img').click(function () {
        var productLinks = $(this).closest('a').attr('href');
        window.open(productLinks, '_blank');
        window.focus();

    });

});
```

Comment: I don't why it works in jsfiddle but not the wordpress site.

http://harmonyjewellers.ca/product-category/designer-watch-special/